# Zabbix 3.4 Bits Received and Sent

Tags: zabbix

I simply want to see my download and upload data in the map section but i couldnt figure out the code.

For example = When i use this ( ''{HOSTNAME : net.if.speed[Interface ge.2.47()].last()}'' ) command it says *UNKNOWN* but I dont know where im doing wrong.

Also tried using ( net.if.in[Interface ge.2.47(Uplink)]:last()} ) but its still not showing any data.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
In: {systemname.with.zabbix:ifInOctets[ppp0].last(0)}
Out: {systemname.with.zabbix:ifOutOctets[ppp0].last(0)}
```

Of course you have to replace the systemname and the interface name (ppp0)
You find the interface names in the items section of the host. (Of course you must have some kind of agent or snmp activated on that host)

[image: Interface names]

Comment: I use a complicated network couldnt find the Incoming network traffic and Outgoing. Only bits received and sent , Interface type , speed etc. And do i need to replace ppp0 with whole key name? For example  {systemname.with.zabbix:ifInOctets[net.if.in[enp3s0]].last(0)}

Comment: So please post what you have for items on that given host. When the numbers are bits received&sent, then you will have to calculate the amount per time.

Comment: It's just like this. https://ibb.co/bQFfpo

Can you change the code if i need a calculation?

Comment: You must use the key names.  `net.if.in[ifHCInOctets.1]` and `net.if.out[ifHCOutOctets.1]`

Comment: So I changed the code to this but its still shows unknown. Sorry to bother you with this.

In: {HostName.with.zabbix:net.if.in[ifHCInOctets.1].last(0)}

Comment: You did not use `HostName.with.zabbix`, but the host name es found in the zabbix host?

Comment: It's done. I found the solution thanks to your help.

Comment: Can you please provide feedback what the problem was, so others with the same problem find a solution here?

Comment: Problem was putting the wrong input in net.if.in[ifHCOutOctets.1]. Your input value has to be provided from only UPLINK bits received or sent. Others wont work out.